# How to ignore validation from Fields inside Hidden Div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore:''});
            $("#Form_Name").validate({
                ignore: "",
                wrapper: "div",
                submitHandler: function (form) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ignore: '#divName *'
```

using `div id` all div that are hidden ignore from validation